# Javascript Detecting bound keys

Tags: javascript

Currently I am trying to use javascript to detect alt+shift+key presses. I need to make it work for a keyboard that bounds those three key presses to a single key, but when I try to track that with javascript it only recognizes the fact that alt is being pressed. I know that all three keys are being pressed because some of them activate the firefox menus I am testing on (like alt+shift+e open the edit menu). Has anyone else ever experienced this issue/knows a work around?

To answer Brads question:
Yes if I use alt+shift+key than it seems to work perfectly only when I try to hit the button bound to those keys does it not work.

And for  epascarello:

```
function keyDown(e){
    console.log("ALT:" + e.altKey + " Shift:" + e.shiftKey + " key:" + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    if(e.altKey && e.shiftKey){
        if(e.keyCode == 75){
             function();
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

And this is how it is being called

```
<html onkeydown="return keyDown(event);">
```

Edit

Also a note:

I figured out more information. I am currently using a POS keyboard made by "Cherry" I was looking at the key bindings and the key was bound to "Alt left + shift + key + release shift + release alt left" when I changed the bindings to ""shift + Alt left + key + release shift + release alt left" then the button works. I am not sure why this is and would still like to know a way to fix it for the original issue but this is a fix.

Comment: To be clear: `alt+shift` (using standard keyboard) works, but using your macro keyboard it doesn't?

Comment: How are you detecting it? Show your code